# MySQL: How to get cost in case cost constantly change

Tags: mysql

I have the following data

```
Tabel A     
product date    qty
A       1/6/22  1
A       5/6/22  2
A       9/6/22  5
B       2/6/22  6 


Table B     
product dailydate   cost
A       1/6/22      20
A       8/6/22      50
B       1/6/22      10
B       8/6/22      40
```

I need to calculate cost by date and product

which the condition is cost in table B will start at minimum date(use column dailydate) until there is new cost in same product such as cost/unit of product A in(1/6-7/6 is 20 and from 8/6-15/6, cost/unit of product A is 50

How this query should look like?

Comment: That is doable. One thing though in B you have two A; 1/6/22 in your table. is that a typo?

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, not as a table. Provide needed product-date value(s) and desired output(s) for this data and criteria with explanations. Hint: correlated subquery with sorting and limiting.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can think of:

```sql
SELECT 
*,
CASE 
WHEN (SELECT cost FROM tableB WHERE tableB.product=tableA.product AND tableA.date <= tableB.daily_date LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL 
    THEN ((SELECT cost FROM tableB WHERE tableB.product=tableA.product AND tableA.date <= tableB.daily_date LIMIT 1))
    ELSE (SELECT cost FROM tableB WHERE tableB.product=tableA.product ORDER BY daily_date DESC LIMIT 1)
END AS cost
FROM tableA;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=71e026352b1c8aa99bdcb5d0d389357f)